# How to check if value is in two ranges in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, range

how to check if value is in two ranges in Kotlin?
I would like to write code for example:

```kotlin
when (value) {
  in (1..10) || (20..30) -> {
     do something...
  }
}
```

I know that it's bad, but how to do it in Kotlin?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I know that it's bad" - What exactly is supposed to be bad about checking if a value is within a certain range?

Answer (score 7):

```
when (value) {
  in 1..10, in (20..30) -> {
    // do something...
  }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't find this syntax. Thank you so much!

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression